# Is this a Cantor Set? Nomenclature question.

Tags: lebesgue-measure, cantor-set

I can form the archetypal cantor set by removing the middle third of an interval, and recursively applying the same treatment to the two intervals remaining.

If instead I start with the interval $[0,1]$, and remove the middle fraction $f$ ($0<f<1$), then remove the middle fraction $f^2$ from the remaining two, the middle fraction $f^3$ from each of the remaining 4 and so on. I end up with a set of line segments of total measure $\exp[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(1-f^n)]$ (which converges). This seems to have some of the properties of the Cantor Set - it is a perfect set that is nowhere dense - but it is not measure zero. Is this a Cantor Set? Does this have a name?

Answer (score 2):

When $f < \frac 13$ the resulting set is commonly called a "fat Cantor set". In general I have seen "Smith–Volterra–Cantor set" to refer to the resulting set, see e.g. [this Wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set)

Comment: Is the information in that article correct? It appears to imply that for $f=1/2$ the measure of the complement set on $[0,1]$ diverges, which sounds like nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

At least in my field (dynamical systems) this would be called a Cantor set, yes. In fact we tend to still call "Cantor set" any topological space homeomorphic to the standard middle-third Cantor set.